# Django: aggregating field values from different models

Tags: django, django-models

If your models are structured like this:

```
class Hour(models.Model):
    stat1 = models.FloatField()
    stat2 = models.FloatField()
    stat3 = models.FloatField()

class Day(models):
    hour = models.ForeignKey(Hour) #e.g.: Hour.id=1, Hour.id=2, ..., Hour.id=24

class Weather(models.Model):
    day = models.ForeignKey(Day)
```

NOTE: `hours` might be missing from certain `days` and `stats` might be missing from certain `hours`. The collection of data lacks all hours for every day and all stats for every hour.

What is the best method for summing and averaging the stats over this hierarchy of `models`? For example, lets say I wanted the sum and average of `stat2` at `H5` for all the `days` that `Weather` has data when I know that some of the days don't have data for `H5`?

UPDATE: my own solution, which assumes that Day.id is equal to the hour of the day: e.g. if Day.id == 5, then it's H5 of the day:

```
hours = [[hour for hour in w.day.objects.all() if hour.id==5] \
    for w in Weather.objects.all()]
var2_sum = [sum(h.var2 for h in hours if hasattr(h,'var2'))]
var2_count = [count(h.var2 for h in hours if hasattr(h,'var2'))]
var2_avg = var2_sum / var2_count
```

Comment: Instances of your Day model should contain both a `weather_set` and an `hour_set`, which will give you that instance's related data.

Comment: How are days designated as H1, H2, etc? I don't see that in the model.

Comment: @Garry .. because there are holes in the data sets, I don't have weather_set or hour_set

Comment: @Cole They should only be absent if the Day instance has no related weather or hours.

Comment: @Garry I just mocked up the above example. `Day` has `weather_set`. `Hour` has `day_set`. And how do these relationships make summing and averaging easier than running a bunch of `for loops`?

Comment: @Cole Because without them you'd have no data to put into your `for` loop to begin with. Now that you know where to get the data, writing the view functions you want should be fairly simple. Run `python manage.py shell` and play around with different ways to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: my own solution, which assumes that Day.id is equal to the hour of the day: e.g. if Day.id == 5, then it's H5 of the day:

```
hours = [[hour for hour in w.day.objects.all() if hour.id==5] \
    for w in Weather.objects.all()]
var2_sum = [sum(h.var2 for h in hours if hasattr(h,'var2'))]
var2_count = [count(h.var2 for h in hours if hasattr(h,'var2'))]
var2_avg = var2_sum / var2_count
```

Nested `forloops` are fun and all, but are a brute force way to answer the question. The use of `hasattr` is necessary to avoid have `None` entries into the lists created by list comprehension.